# trying to simplify the update code

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update the following words in the `identifier_flag` field, is there a simpler way to do this than what I currenty have?

```
$temp_query = "select * from faq"; 
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, $temp_query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    if(preg_match("/price/", $row['question'])){
        $update = "update faq set identifier_flag = 'price' where id = '".$row['id']."'";
        mysqli_query($connection, $update);
    }
    if(preg_match("/colours/", $row['question'])){
        $update = "update faq set identifier_flag = 'colours' where id = '".$row['id']."'";
        mysqli_query($connection, $update);
    }
    if(preg_match("/versions/", $row['question'])){
        $update = "update faq set identifier_flag = 'versions' where id = '".$row['id']."'";
        mysqli_query($connection, $update);
    }
    if(preg_match("/oil/", $row['question'])){
        $update = "update faq set identifier_flag = 'oil' where id = '".$row['id']."'";
        mysqli_query($connection, $update);
    }
    if(preg_match("/seating/", $row['question'])){
        $update = "update faq set identifier_flag = 'seating' where id = '".$row['id']."'";
        mysqli_query($connection, $update);
    }

    if(preg_match("/warranty/", $row['question'])){
        $update = "update faq set identifier_flag = 'warranty' where id = '".$row['id']."'";
        mysqli_query($connection, $update);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the goal of that query? At the moment you are connecting to database multiple times and running the update the row. If you mention the goal of this query, may be I can suggest you the optimized query without having to connect multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

So many ways to do this.
My brain would see it like this

```
$temp_query = "select * from faq"; 
$flags = ['flag1','flag2'];
$sql = mysqli_query($connection,$temp_query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){

    foreach($flags as $k=>$v) {
        if(preg_match('/'.$v.'/',$row['question'])) {
            $update = "update faq set identifier_flag = '{$v}' where id = '".$row['id']."'";
            mysqli_query($connection,$update);
            //continue; //to go to the next result
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer...if i will have 50 cases then i have to write 50 switch cases right!...can't we keep in array and check

Comment: The real problem is the initial insert of your data should be creating the correct 'identifier_flag'. Smells of a design problem. But I like the switches better than the ifelseifelseifelseifelse.......

Comment: yes...i am stuck with the logic i hope we can go with one if condition by keeping all keywords into one array